# Django Rest Framework DELETE returns no content in the body

Tags: python, django, redux, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework and I am making a DELETE request. As opposed to POST, PUT, PATCH, which all return the state of the object post creation/modification, delete does not return anything in the body (just the 204 code).

Having this information would be helpful when trying to tie responses back to their original requests. In particular https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware does a bad job at telling me what succeeded and what errored)

Is there a way to force DRF to add information about what was deleted in the body of the response?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure thing. In your view, you'll have to override `destroy`. Default implementation -by the time of writing this answer- is:

```
def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object()
    self.perform_destroy(instance)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 14):

Complementing @Linovia's otherwise complete answer with actionable code.

In the ViewSet, adding the following will help

```
class WhateverYourModelIsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def destroy(self, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(self.get_object())
        super().destroy(*args, **kwargs)
        return response.Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Few things to be aware of:

- Returning 204 code will actually drop the data, you have to return something else
- You need to extract the data from the serializer *before* you call destroy

**Edit:**

Since I first posted my answer, I found myself in need to do the above quite often. A more scalable solution:

```
class DestroyWithPayloadMixin(object):
     def destroy(self, *args, **kwargs):
         serializer = self.get_serializer(self.get_object())
         super().destroy(*args, **kwargs)
         return response.Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

class WhateverYourModelIsViewSet(DestroyWithPayloadMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   # Your implementation 
   pass
```

Comment: When the field on ModelSerializer is `serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)` its value is empty on Response. It works fine with fields like `PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False)` and normal model field. What should I add in the code to fix it?